# Android - Dynamically created tabs can only be clicked once

Tags: android, dynamic, tabs

I'm probably doing something stupid... I have one statically created tab and a pile of dynamically created tabs on the same tabhost. The static tab is displayed by default. When I click on one of the dynamically created tabs, it loads the dynamic content correctly. But when I click on any other tab after that regardless of whether it was dynamically or statically created, it will not do anything. Any idea why?

Here is what I'm trying to do in MyActivitys onResume method:

```
final TabHost tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
tabs.setup();

// Tab with static content
TabHost.TabSpec instructions = tabs.newTabSpec("instructions");
tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        setTabColors(tabs); 
    } 
});
instructions.setContent(R.id.instructions); 
instructions.setIndicator("Instructions");
tabs.addTab(instructions);

// Tabs with dynamic content
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    TabHost.TabSpec category = tabs.newTabSpec("cat" + i);
    final boolean m_editable = editable;
    category.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {  
            ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(MyActivity.this);
            TableLayout dataMatrix = new TableLayout(MyActivity.this);                  
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);   
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
                TableRow item = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.categorydata_entry, dataMatrix, false);
                ((EditText)(item.getChildAt(0))).setText("row"+i);
            }
            dataMatrix.addView(item,new TableLayout.LayoutParams( TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        scrollView.addView(dataMatrix);
        return scrollView;
    } 
});
category.setIndicator(i);
tabs.addTab(category);                      
    }
```

And the relevant element in layout.xml:

```
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tabHost" > 
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:fillViewport="true" 
        android:scrollbars="none" >
        <TabWidget 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/instructions" > 
            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:text="This is the static content tab" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>          
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found my mistake. In case anyone else runs into the same difficulty: for whatever reason, the tabContent cannot be a ScrollView.

Putting a LinearLayout container around the scroll view made everything work as expected.